# ODBC working only with sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, centos-7, odbc

I'm having troubles with unixODBC. I've installed the latest version and currently is working only with `sudo`. To test the ODBC I've used `isql`. Example:

```
# isql -v testTable
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

With `sudo`

```
# sudo isql -v testTable
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Why is that and how can I use it without `sudo`?

Note: I didn't used `sudo` while installed it. And I installed it as a root and trying to use it as a root.

UPDATE

```
# ls -ltr /usr/local/psql/etc/odbcinst.ini
ls: cannot access /usr/local/psql/etc/odbcinst.ini: No such file or directory
# ls -ltr /etc/odbcinst.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 740 28 nov  8,04 /etc/odbcinst.ini
```

Content of `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
~]# cat /etc/odbcinst.ini


# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage   = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage   = 1
```

Update `/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[myDSN]
Description         = MySQL Connection
Driver              = MySQL
Database            = testTable
User                = mysql
Password            = ******
Port                = 3310
Server              = localhost
Socket              = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Another update. Without sudo:

```
odbcinst -j
-bash: /usr/local/bin/odbcinst: No such file or directory
```

With sudo

```
sudo odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Check /etc/odbcinst.ini, /etc/odbc.ini, ~/.odbc.ini and $ODBCINI to see what rights are assigned. I believe the user running the command may not have rights to one of those files, or may not even have the data source defined if it was created under a different user.

Taken from [Common Error Messages](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/FAQ#Common%20Error%20Messages) and 
[What's an odbc.ini and what do I put in it?](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/FAQ#What%27s%20an%20odbc.ini%20and%20what%20do%20I%20put%20in%20it%3F)
Further more, check the /etc/odbc.ini and ~/.odbc.ini of the user you added the DSN to, plus the user you are running as.  If these are the same, you only need to do this once.

---

### Common Error Messages

> [iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default
>   driver specified. Driver could not be loaded, SQLSTATE=IM002
>
> There are several reasons why this message could occur. The best solution is to
>   trace through what's happening: your application has been linked
>   against libiodbc, which has tried to find an odbc.ini file one way or
>   another - either through the ODBCINI environment variable or the
>   fall-back paths (typically /etc/odbc.ini, depending on how it was
>   compiled). You should check that such a file exists in a suitable
>   location, and that it is accessible (particularly if your application
>   runs with different user privileges - such as apache/php running as a
>   www-data user).
>
> Additionally, it could be that iODBC has found a suitable odbc.ini
>   file, but none of the file(s) found contain the DSN you've requested.
>   Check the syntax of your request - is the ODBC connect-string correct,
>   and does the DSN you're requesting exist? See also the section of this
>   FAQ, above, entitled `What's an odbc.ini and what do I put in it?'.

---

### What's an odbc.ini

> An odbc.ini is the main configuration file in which all your DSNs and
>   much of the ODBC configuration parameters are stored. iODBC has a
>   search-path for finding such a configuration file: first, the
>   environment variable ODBCINI is inspected to see if it points at a
>   suitable file, or ~/.odbc.ini (analagous to User DSNs on Windows) then
>   /etc/odbc.ini ("system-wide") are fall-back locations.
>
> The odbc.ini file comprises 3 parts: a set of ODBC options, a list of
>   DSNs, and then the datasource definitions themselves, thus:

```
[ODBC Data Sources] 
PostgreSQL native localhost = PostgreSQL native driver 
PostgreSQL OpenLink localhost = PostgreSQL over OpenLink multi-tier

[PostgreSQL native localhost] 
Driver     = /usr/lib/postgresql/lib/libodbcpsql.so 
Host       = localhost 
Server     = localhost 
ServerName = localhost 
Database   = tim 
UserName   = tim 
UID        = tim 
Port       = 5432

[PostgreSQL OpenLink localhost]
Description     = PostgreSQL, over openlink MT 
Driver          = /opt/openlink/lib/oplodbc.so 
ServerType      = PostgreSQL95 
Host            = localhost 
Database        = tim 
Username        = tim 
LastUser        = tim 
User            = tim
FetchBufferSize = 99

[ODBC] 
;Trace = 1 
;TraceFile = /tmp/odbctrace.log ;Debug = 1
;DebugFile = /tmp/odbcdebug.log
```

> The list of ODBC Data Sources
>   correlate with the file odbcinst.ini (or environment variable
>   ODBCINSTINI): for every value used as a description of the driver
>   there should be a corresponding section in odbcinst.ini listing both
>   the Driver and Setup library (to assist with graphical configuration
>   using iodbcadm-gtk, and also used to display an input box in the event
>   of insufficient options being presented at connection-time).
>
> The list of attributes is driver-dependent, as the above shows: the
>   native postgresql driver calls them different things from openlink
>   multi-tier, so you have to check with your driver's documentation.
>
> With iODBC, assuming you downloaded/installed/compiled it, you also
>   have a GTK-based GUI for configuring your ODBC DSNs, too: run
>   iodbcadm-gtk.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69395/discussion-on-answer-by-netniv-odbc-working-only-with-sudo).